# Referencing R file

Tags: android, apk, robotium

I am using robotium test project where I need a way for referring to an R file of application which is under test and fetch id's.

Already tried to pull R file from apk and copy it in test project. It dint help.

Kindly let me know if there is a way?

Comment: R.java is automatically generated when you build your project, no need to copy it from somewhere else, just clean and build your project and it should update itself (ex: as for id, in your layout xml files) and make sure that you are importing R from your project name, not android.R

Comment: That's right.  But I am not talking about my projects R file. I want to refer to application   under test from my test project. I only have apk no source code.  That's how robotium works.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/r0Q3AvOFYYw

Comment: http://ekasiswanto.wordpress.com/2012/09/19/descriptions-of-androids-resources-arsc/

Comment: in general, search for arsc -- there's resources.arsc in the apk. Android definitely already has the functionality to read it, and probably it may be re-used.

Comment: In the Android source, frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/content/PackageHelper.java mentions arsc.

Comment: Thanks. I will go through the link's and try using it to read R file.